# Duplicating elements in a list

Tags: haskell

I have a list, for example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and I have to duplicate each element of the list to form a list like [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5].

As a hint, we're referred to the concat function which flattens a list of lists into a single list. But to try and understand how you would go about this in Haskell better, I'm trying to do it manually. Here is my attempt:

```
duplicate :: [a] -> [a]
duplicate [] = []
duplicate (x:xs) =  x : (x:xs) duplicate xs
```

With the error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `((a0 -> Bool) -> [a0] -> [a0])
                                  -> [a] -> [a]'
                with actual type `[a]'
    The function `x : xs' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `[a]' has none
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(x : xs) myTakeWhile xs'
    In the expression: x : (x : xs) myTakeWhile xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My way of thinking is that you cons the head of the list to the whole list and then recursively call the function on the tail of this list. For example in pseudocode:

```
duplicate [1, 2, 3]

1 : [1, 2, 3] duplicate [2, 3]

2 : [2, 3] duplicate [3]

3: [3] duplicate []

return list [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Is this an idiomatic way of approaching this problem and where am I going wrong in my attempt syntactically? I'm not looking for alternative, more efficient code solutions to this, I'm merely trying to get used to the functional way of approaching problems as opposed to imperative ways of looking at things.

Thanks!

Comment: `x y` always means 'apply function `x` to argument `y`'. In `[1, 2, 3] function`, `[1, 2, 3]` is not a function, hence the type error.

Comment: Your thinking is correct, but you applied the function incorrectly. The code as it is attempts to view the list as a function to which you pass `myTakeWhile` and the list. Perhaps, duplicate the tail first, then append the head twice to that.

Comment: myTakeWhile was a copy error, was trying to call duplicate recursively. Have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition you're looking for is:

```
duplicate :: [a] -> [a]
duplicate [] = []
duplicate (x:xs) =  x : x : duplicate xs
```

Since `:` is a right-associative operator, you can read that last alternative as

```
duplicate (x:xs) =  x : (x : (duplicate xs))
```

or as

```
duplicate (x:xs) =  (:) x ((:) x (duplicate xs))
```

Keeping in mind that `[1, 2, 3]` is just short for `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, when `duplicate` is applied to `[1, 2, 3]`, the second alternative is used because it matches the pattern `x : xs` (namely with `x = 1` and `xs = 2 : 3 : []`). You want the result to begin twice with the head (which is the `x : x : ...` part of the definition), and continue with the duplicated tail (the `... : duplicate xs` part).

Comment: So my way of thinking works! Just a little bit off with the syntax, thanks!

Comment: @Bradley I really wish Haskell's list syntax wasn't so utterly confusing to people who want to pick up Haskell :/

Comment: Haskell has a huge learning curve, especially for people who were brought up on imperative languages. I find that I'm spending most of my time figuring out how to represent what I'm thinking in a syntactically correct manner

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing, but through structured recursion is: duplicate = foldr (\a b -> a:a:b) []